# Classifying space of a Group: Reference Request

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

I am planing to self-study the notion of [classifying spaces.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space#Examples) Do any of you know a self contained reference (Books, lecture notes, or videos) on this subject suitable for a beginner?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Cohen's notes on fiber bundles are quite good. I'm not sure if its exactly what you're looking for, but you will need to know about fibrations in order to understand classifying spaces. He talks about classifying spaces in chapter 2. http://math.stanford.edu/~ralph/fiber.pdf

Comment: @ElliotG: Thank you for the linked note. Currently I know nothing about  fibrations, but I will definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Milnor's original paper is very readable, but I've heard forom some people they prefer more modern constructions. For fibrations, Stephen Mitchell has notes on these and also notes on principal bundles which he approaches via lifting arguments that only have his fibration notes as prerequisites.